# Experiment describing superconductivity discovery

Tags: condensed-matter, electricity, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

We study in Ohm's law that current $I$ is directly proportional to voltage difference $V$ between two points, where resistance $R$ is the proportionality constant.

In 1911, if K. Onnes measured electrical resistance to be 0 at critical temperature, then

"As we can't directly measure resistance $R$, and to measure $R$, we need $V$ value, and if resistance is zero, we know that current still remains in the superconductor. But resistance being equal to 0 must imply $V=0$, and if $V=0$ then there must be no current.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Kindly do not close this question and don't give me articles to see the answer as I am asking this question second time, as I think it is a small minor conceptual question which I am missing.

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: You're just confused because Ohm's law $V = I R$ doesn't apply in superconductors. Heck, it doesn't even work in a light bulb.

Comment: "Kindly do not close this question..." Just in case this question does get closed, which I suspect it might, please be aware that there are other forums on the internet that may be more accepting of this kind of question.

Comment: @DanielSank what is the actual answer then. How can we explain it then?

Comment: If you [read this article](https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/history/cold/DelftKes_HKO_PT.pdf) you will note that Onnes wrote in his notebook "Kwik
nagenoeg nul" which means “Mercury[‘s resistance] practically zero [at $3 \rm K$] and the graph that has a fall in resistance to $10^{-5}\Omega$ coupled with a statement that "Within $0.01 \rm K$, the resistance jumps from unmeasurably
small (less than $10^{–6}\Omega)$ to $0.1 \Omega$."